# Django logging is empty

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, logging

I'm having a problem, what on Earth just happened after I added a formatter to the LOGGING configuration? The logging file is empty.

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{asctime} [{module}]:: {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'file.DEBUG': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/debug.log',
            'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10,
            'backupCount': 10,
            'formatter':'verbose'
        },
        'file.INFO': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/info.log',
            'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10,
            'formatter':'verbose'
        },
        'file.ERROR': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/error.log',
            'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10,
            'backupCount': 10,
            'formatter':'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file.DEBUG'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file.INFO'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file.ERROR'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Now all the outputed debug files are empty except for the error file which I tested on the view with this code

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django')

logger.info('tests')
logger.error('tests')
logger.debug('tests')
logger.debug('tests')
logger.error('tests')
logger.info('tests')
```

Only the error is being logged on the file, why is this happening?
I'm using the new version of django which is 2.2

Update
Don't know what just I did but its working now
This is my new LOGGING setting

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
                'format': '{levelname} {asctime} [{module}]:: {message}',
                'style': '{',
            },
            'simple': {
                'format': '{levelname} {message}',
                'style': '{',
            },
        },
    'handlers': {
        'file_debug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG', 
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/debug.log',
            'formatter':'verbose'
        },
        'file_error': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/error.log',
            'formatter':'verbose'
        },
        'file_info': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/info.log',
            'formatter':'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['file_debug'], 
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True, 
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file_error'], 
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True, 
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file_info'], 
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True, 
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not configure the [**`LOGGING`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/). In your settings you have two entries for `django`, and django is writing logs based on the last entry. Instead of that, you should have put the configuration like this:

```
'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file.DEBUG'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file.INFO', 'file.ERROR'],  # <-- Here
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        }
}
```

Please see the last example of the [**`examples section`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#examples) of documentation.

Comment: It was working before I added formatter, also I want every log levels has its own file. But thanks to the info, about `django.request ` :)